# double where statement in SQL and ASP

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access

I am a little lost on how to incorporate TWO Where in my sql statement in my asp. 
I am trying to get the userID and password entered previously and compare it with what I have in my database created on SQL:

I think my problem comes from my double quotation and single quotation.
UserID is a number in my database and Password is a short text.

```
var mycon = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var myrec = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset"); 
mycon.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Omnivox.mdb"); 
var txtpassword = Request.QueryString("txtpassword");
var txtuserID = parseInt (Request.QueryString("txtuserID"));
var sql;
sql = "SELECT UserID, UserPassword FROM UserOmnivox WHERE UserID=" +txtuserID+ " AND UserPassword='" + txtpassword + "';";    
myrec.Open(sql, mycon);
```

thank you

UPDATE: It is still not working. The error massage is : no value given for one or more required parameters for the line myrec.Open(sql,mycon)

Comment: Passwords shouldn't be stored in plaintext in the database. They should be one way hashed and salted, and you should compare the hashed forms of the passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM UserOmnivox WHERE UserID=" +txtuserID "AND UserPassword="'+txtpassword';
```

to

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM UserOmnivox WHERE UserID=" +txtuserID + " AND UserPassword='"+txtpassword+"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd done any kind of basic debugging, like LOOKING at the query string you're generating, you'd have seen this:

```
sql = "SELECT [..snip..] UserID=" +txtuserID "AND UserPassword="'+txtpassword
                                             ^^--- no space
                                              ^--- missing +
```

which produces

```
SELECT .... UserID=1234AND userPassword
                      ^^---syntax error, no such field '1234AND'
```

And then, yes, your quotes are wrong too

```
sql = "SELECT ... UserID=" +txtuserID "AND UserPassword="'+txtpassword
      ^------------------^-- one string
                                      ^-----------------^-- another string
                                                         ^---???
```

It should be

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM UserOmnivox WHERE UserID=" +txtuserID + " AND UserPassword='" + txtpassword + "';";
```

Comment: This construct is allowed in some databases, notably SQL Server parses it correctly.  I don't know if MS Access does.

Comment: maybe for integers, but if that was a dynamically inserted field name, it'd be a parse error. no way to tell where the field name leaves off and the boolean operator starts.

Comment: It is still not working. The error massage is : no value given for one or more required parameters for the line myrec.Open(sql,mycon)

Answer (score 0):

I find another more flexible solution is better.  Sometimes based on conditions you have one where condition, in others you have zero, and in others you have two.  If you go down these paths they don't solve that issue.  The following does.....

```
Some sql query
where 1=1  -- ## A condition that will always be true and does nothing to your query. 
and first optional where clause
and second optional where clause
```

This way if you don't have the first where clause in a given situation but you do have the second you are not missing the words "where".  You always have the where and you optionally add any array of "and" parts to your where statement.  100% flexibility in this method works for all challenges.  Plus it is easier to follow code once you get past the wtf is this 1=1 nonsense reaction.

Comment: For example what if I had a web singles page that allowed you to select by zodiac sign, and income level.  In one case they may select only Zodiac sign, in the other case they may select only income level.  In another case they may select neither and another case they may select both.  This logic works with the 1=1 logic and optionally add in the "and" conditions for zodiac or income level.